# Issue on Concatenation in Array Push

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects which first array looks like

[image]

now in client side I want to create an index array and store the value projects in there  but I am getting 8 `undefined` in the array

```
var roadsArr =[];
for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) { 
  roadsArr.push(data[1].ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_+[i]);    
}
```

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: show your "data" array structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
roadsArr.push(data[1].ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_+[i]);
```

You can't construct an immediate property name like that, you'd need:

```
roadsArr.push(data[1]['ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_' + i]);
```

That aside, if you have an ordered sequence of object members, consider using an actual array instead of an ad-hoc, brittle name-based mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Dave but I am still getting undefined!

Comment: @Suffii Then either (1) there's no `roadsArr`, or (2) there's no `data[1]`, or (3) you're confused about array indexing in JS, or (4) the error comes from someplace else. You don't provide much usable information. Also, text should be posted as test, not images.

Comment: this should work. like @DaveNewton said, data[1] does not exist or the latter. Try data[0] or you may possibly want data['ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_' + i] ... like i am trying to say, we cant really help you because there isnt enough information

Comment: Otherwise, post more information so that we can help you. The exact names and structures of the data objects/arrays you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps `data[1].ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_+[i]` should be: `data[1].ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_+i`

Comment: Thanks Denny this is generating `nan` in the array!

Comment: No it shouldn't be, this JS would attempt to add `1` to the value at `data[1].ecolo_roads_Projects_Step_`.